# How do we name a Visualforce PDF without Apex (Filename)

Tags: visualforce, pdf, renderas, doctype

Here is our Visualforce Page Attributes
In this example we are trying to name the PDF "Hello"

```
<apex:page title="PDFPage" renderAs="pdf" standardStylesheets="false" standardcontroller="custom_object__c" docType="html-5.0" showHeader="false" sidebar="false" recordSetVar="customObjVar" contentType="application/pdf#hello" >
```

**How do we name a Visualforce PDF without Apex?**

Normally in Apex this is what we do:

```
Apexpages.currentPage().getHeaders().put('content-disposition', 'attachment; filename=hello.pdf');
```

**So how do we set the content-disposition parameter using visualforce?**

**UPDATE**
When we change the renderas="html", it tries to open the document in Adobe (default pdf application) as expected, and with the correct filename, but of course Adobe errors because the content is not pdf, so application/pdf#filename works but not when renderas="pdf"
Weird!